# Django passing view url variables inside a template

Tags: python, django, web

I feel like this is going to be an embarrassing question but I can't find the answer I've tried google but I am getting fairly frustrated so I just decided to ask here. 
I've got this code snippet inside a template file in django

```
{% url cal.views.month year month "next" %}
```

I run the code and get this error
Reverse for 'courseCalendar.views.month' with arguments '(2013, 9, u'next')' not found

Why is it that when I try to pass variables in a string it puts the u in there as well. This is very frustrating and I would really appreciate someones two cents.

Edit: Everything works fine if I don't include the string "next" and use a variable instead like the year and month variables so it's not a url problem or template problem.

url pattern

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', 'courseCalendar.views.main'),
    url(r'^month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<change>[a-z])/$', 'courseCalendar.views.month', name="month"),

)
```

Views

```
# Create your views here.
import time
import calendar
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
#from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required    For login requirements. 
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from courseCalendar.models import *

monthNames = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jly Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec"
monthNames = monthNames.split()


#@login_required  This should be uncommented in the future but for now we don't want to     deal with it. Default set to 2013 for now.
def main(request, year="None"):

if year == "None":
    year = time.localtime()[0]
else:
    year = int(year)

currentYear,currentMonth = time.localtime()[:2]
totalList = []

for y in [year]:
    monthList = []
    for n, month in enumerate(monthNames):
        course = current = False
        courses = Course.objects.filter(courseDate__year=y, courseDate__month=n+1)

        if courses:
            course = True
        if y==currentYear and n+1 == currentMonth:
            current = True
        monthList.append(dict(n=n+1, name=month, course=course, current=current))
    totalList.append((y,monthList))

#return render_to_response("courseCalendar/Templates/main.html", dict(years=totalList, user=request.user, year=year, reminders=reminders(request)))   <-- Later in the build
return render_to_response("main.html", dict(years=totalList, user=request.user, year=year))





def month(request, year=1, month=1, change="None"):


if year == "None":
    year = time.localtime()[0]
else:
    year = int(year)


if month == "None":
    month = time.localtime()[1]
else:
    month = int(month)

if change in ("next", "prev"):
    todaysDate, mdelta = date(year, month, 15), timedelta(days=31)
    if change == "next":
        mod = mdelta
    elif change == "prev":
        mod = -mdelta
    year, month = (todaysDate+mod).timertuple()[:2]


cal = calendar.Calendar()
month_days = cal.itermonthdays(year, month)
nyear, nmonth, nday = time.localtime()[:3]
lst = [[]]
week = 0


for day in month_days:
    courses = current = False

    if day:
        courses = Course.objects.filter(courseDate__year=year, courseDate__month=month, courseDate__day=day)
        if day == nday and year == nyear and month == nmonth:
            current = True

    lst[week].append((day, courses, current))
    if len(lst[week]) == 7:
        lst.append([])
        week += 1

return render_to_response("month.html", dict(year=year, month=month, user=request.user, month_days=lst, monthNames=monthNames[month-1]))
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Need to figure out how to pass the year variable properly in the url arguements. The way it was originally written didn't work  and adding quotes appended a "u" to the areguements-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Year View</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "courseCalendar/css/layout.css" %}" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="{% url "courseCalendar.views.main" %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
    <a href="{% url "courseCalendar.views.main" %}">Next &gt;&gt;</a>

    {% for year, months in years %}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <h4>{{ year }}</h4>
        {% for month in months %}
            <div class=
            {% if month.current %}"month current"{% endif %}
            {% if not month.current %}"month"{% endif %}
            >
                {% if month.entry %}<b>{% endif %}
                <a href="{% url "courseCalendar.views.month" year month "next"">{{ month.name }}</a>
                {% if month.entry %}</b>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

month.html

```
<a href="{% url "courseCalendar.views.month" %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
<a href="{% url "courseCalendar.views.month" %}">Next &gt;&gt;</a>

<h4>{{ month }} {{ year }}</h4>

<div class="month">
<table>

<tr>
    <td class="empty">Mon</td>
    <td class="empty">Tue</td>
    <td class="empty">Wed</td>
    <td class="empty">Thu</td>
    <td class="empty">Fri</td>
    <td class="empty">Sat</td>
    <td class="empty">Sun</td>
</tr>

{% for week in month_days %}
    <tr>
    {% for day, courses, current in week %}
        <td class= {% if day == 0 %}"empty"{% endif %}
        {% if day != 0 and not current %}"day"{% endif %}
        {% if day != 0 and current %}"current"{% endif %}
        {% if day != 0 %}"Add day click code here"{% endif %} >

        {% if day != 0 %}
            {{ day }}
            {% for course in courses %}
                <br />
                <b>{{ course.courseCreator }}</b>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the url pattern.

Comment: what is your url.py and why a ' sign at the end ?

Comment: url(r'^month$', 'courseCalendar.views.month', name='month')
The ' is a typo at the end. It finds the page without the "next" argument fyi it's not problem with my url I don't think.

Comment: How are you passing parameters to the view? You didn't even add the parameters in the url pattern.

Comment: The parameters are passed by the year and month variables. They all work. All the pages show up and parameters are accessible. The problem is when I use a string instead of the year or month variable I get the "u" inside of the string.

Comment: You don't have to worry about the _u_ It only stands for *unicode*. The source of your problem might be one of those mentioned on the comment section.

Comment: post your full url pattern

Comment: As @Hardy said, post all the url patterns.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'', 'courseCalendar.views.month', name='month'),
      url(r'^month$', 'courseCalendar.views.month', name='month'),
)
It's not very big it's a small project right now

Comment: Go through it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/
You're doing it wrong.

Comment: One more thing, post your view parameters.

Comment: def month(request, year="None", month="None", change="None"):

Comment: `url(r'^month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<change>[a-z])/$', 'courseCalendar.views.month'),`

Comment: I tried this and I still haven't been able to solve the issue. I'll keep reading and maybe I'll be able to find the solution

Comment: There's no specific error now it just gives me a url with "/%7B%%20url". I must be doing something wrong I don't know why that is the generated url.

Comment: `def month(request, year="None", month="None", change="None"):` change the year and month to integers.

Comment: would it be helpful if i just posted my views and template files as well? i feel like im running in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the following:

In your view file:

```
def month(request, year=1, month=1, change="None"):
```

In your url file:

```
url(r'^month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<change>\w+)/$', 'courseCalendar.views.month', name="month"),
```

After you change to the above, post here the error message if you're receiving an error.

Comment: Reverse for 'courseCalendar.views.month' with arguments '(2013, 1, u'next')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: I changed my url file to accept the calling of month with and without parameters and I was able to solve the issue thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: url(r'^month/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<change>\w+)$', 'courseCalendar.views.month'),
also changed your url to this